# How to merge collectAsState() in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In my app i have two `collectAsState()`. I want to use this basis of some logic, when route is home then this two `collectAsState()` combine and give me the result

```
val tradeOrderList by tradeViewModel.tradeViewState.fetchOrderList.collectAsState()
val tradeAlgoOrderList by tradeViewModel.tradeViewState.fetchAlgoOrderList.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
    if (route == context.getString(R.string.home)){

    }
}
```

when route is home then `tradeOrderList` and `tradeAlgoOrderList` combine
how can i do this? Thank you

Comment: U can use "Zip" or "Combine"  function to combine 2 flows /states and read it

Comment: this two variable type is same NetworkResult<BaseResponse<ResponseOrderList>>?, i want to combine this two varible and return me NetworkResult<BaseResponse<ResponseOrderList>>? type collectAsState()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
val tradeOrderList by tradeViewModel.tradeViewState.fetchOrderList.collectAsState()
val tradeAlgoOrderList by tradeViewModel.tradeViewState.fetchAlgoOrderList.collectAsState()

var mergedList by remember { mutableStateOf<NetworkResult<BaseResponse<ResponseOrderList>>?>(null) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = route) {
    snapshotFlow { route } // to avoid multiple events when the route wasn't changed.
        .collect {
            if (it == context.getString(R.string.home)){
                mergedList = ... // make some mapping here
            }
        }
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "combine". Whether you want to make a list of two objects or something else. Please provide the structure of your `NetworkResult<BaseResponse<ResponseOrderList>>?` and explain what do you want to see after "combining"